# "Is it okay for you?" Is this phrase considered formal in school/college setting?

Tags: formal-language, register

If I emailed my teacher:

> I've said that I can stay after school to make up the test, but I found out that I have a band rehersal tomorrow. Is it okay for you if I take it on wednesday after school instead?

is the phrase *is it OK for you* formal in a student-teacher correspondence?

I feel like asking your teacher "is that okay for you?" is not formal and sounds like I'm talking to my friends.

and maybe any grammatical mistakes?

Answer (score 5):

Because of your situation:

> I've said that I can stay after school to make up the test, but I found out that I have a band rehearsal tomorrow.

Your request to reschedule is a form of **asking permission** which can be phrased using either **would** which would sound neither too formal nor informal.

> **Is it okay for you if I take it on wednesday after school instead?**
>
> > **Would it be okay** if I took the makeup on Wednesday after school instead?
> >
> > **Would I be able to reschedule** and take the test on Wednesday after school instead?
> >     **Would it be possible to reschedule** the makeup for after school on Wednesday?

Using **could** would ask more about **agreement** rather than **permission**

> I was wondering if **I could reschedule** the makeup until Wednesday?
>   **Could** we reschedule the makeup until Wednesday?

Your teacher will let you know if they are agreeable to the change or not.

More informally you might use:

> Can we reschedule for Wednesday? **Does that work for you**?

Answer (score 2):

In short, I would send that to a teacher and not worry about it. It's not informal, but also isn't formal, and while it isn't exactly how I'd phrase it (as a native speaker) it's grammatically correct.

A slight correction, normally we would say "Is it okay *with* you if..."

If you are trying to get a bit more formal, you could say "Would it be alright with you if..." or "Would it be possible for me to take it..."

(Note I feel like your phrasing and my "would it be..." phrasing is a bit more presumptuous, like you made your own plans and are just running them by the teacher and are expecting a yes. My second phrasing is more polite and leaves more room for a yes or no. But this is pretty picky, and I don't think the teacher will read that much into it, especially if she knows you aren't a native speaker)

Comment: do native speakers never ask "is it okay for you.." and are there any parts that  doesnt sound native? @Sarah

Comment: The only time I would say that is something like "Is it okay for you to *do something*", such as "Is it okay for you to eat peanuts?", I wouldn't say "Is it okay for you if...".

Comment: Also, your tenses in the first sentence are fine, but if I were writing this in my own words, I probably would have said "I said [earlier/yesterday/before etc] that I could stay after school tomorrow, but I found out I have a band rehearsal at that time" Like I said, yours is correct, it just sounds ever so slightly awkward. @Maimai123

Comment: See also this post on the okay for/okay with question  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196878/whats-the-difference-between-is-it-ok-for-you-and-is-it-ok-with-you/196879

Comment: someone answered that this sounds native. A: I’d like to get together with you at 3:00 this afternoon. Is that time ok for you?B: I’m afraid not. I have another appointment at 3:00, but 4:30 is ok for me.  why is this good but asking "is it okay for you if.." sounds awkward? @Sarah

Comment: @Maimai123: I would say there's a subtle distinction between *Is X okay **for** you?* (if and when X happens, will that be okay from your perspective?) and *Is X okay **by** you?* (I'm passing this *by* you to ask if you will "okay it"). The first could reasonably be asked even if your reaction couldn't possibly affect the actual decision to be made, but the second implies you're actually being asked to grant "permission" for a proposed course of action.

Comment: @Sarah: Regardless of the preposition, *okay by/for someone* is very much an informal usage. Whether it's suitable in OP's context depends on the level of formality expected by the teacher, but it's unlikely the teacher would think there was anything actually *wrong* with ***Is it acceptable to you if...*** even if she would have been quite happy with more informal phrasing.

Comment: @fumblefingers yes you're correct, it's informal. To me, it is plenty formal enough for any teacher I've had (as opposed to something like, hey I can't be there tomorrow, is it cool if I do it Wednesday? as an example of too informal), but I should have recognized that different teachers expect different levels of formality. Like i said in my original response, I see this as neutrally formal, but others might classify it as informal.

Comment: Sarah: Yes, we might all have different ideas about exactly where on the formal/informal continuum we should position student/teacher email communications. Indeed, it may be that OP himself might wish to push things slightly in one direction or the other (after taking account of the *teacher's* expectations, since there would be additional implications if he strayed too far from that as a "baseline"). In which context we must note that *cool -> okay -> alright - > acceptable -> satisfactory* are "points" on that continuum, and the ***okay*** position is nearer one end than the other.